# How can a loaded child swf 1 communicate to next child swf, child swf 2, which is currently not loaded

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a parent swf with three buttons: next button, back button, ticker on/off button.
I have three child swfs, each with a ticker mc. When I click on ticker button on parent swf
it dispatches a custom event which brings ticker MC on stage and thus ticker becomes visible (ticker off button displaces it out of stage by changing the value of ticker_mc.y).
the problem I am facing is when ticker is on and I click next or back button to load next or previous child swf, the ticker goes off. How can I make sure that ticker is on all the time and closes only when I close it. How can a loaded child swf 1 communicate to next child swf, child swf 2, which is currently not loaded, that since the ticker is on on swf 1 so you please keep the ticker on on swf 2 as well?!

I think I know the problem. I have put a default value of ticker_mc = 160 (makes ticker inactive) on every child swf. So, the ticker becomes inactive everytime I load a new child swf. If someone could guide how can I do this, my problem will be solved: When first child swf is loaded, the default value of ticker_mc.y should be 160. I want to hold this value in a variable. When I click ticker active btn, position of ticker_mc changes to 194 so the value of variable should change to 194. When I click next btn, the variable value (160 or 194) should be sent to next child swf and ticker_mc.y should be equal to variable value.

This is the code so far

"Next button"

```
go_mc.next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playNext);

function playNext(e:MouseEvent):void {
if (swf_no < (clips.length-1)) {
    swf_no++;

    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    nextClip();

    pp.play_btn.visible=false;
    pp.pause_btn.visible=true;


}
```

}

```
function nextClip():void {
    thisLoader.load(new URLRequest(clips[swf_no]));
```

}

//Every time I click next or back button this event is called and I remove previous swf from stage.

```
thisLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoading);
function doneLoading(e:Event):void {

stopAllChildMovieClips(stage);
stage.removeChild(thisMC);

thisMC=MovieClip(thisLoader.content);
thisLoader.unloadAndStop();

thisMC.x=37;
thisMC.y=78.50;

stage.addChild(thisMC);
playAllChildMovieClips(stage);
```

}

//Ticker active button on parent swf

```
viewUnviewTxt_mc.viewTxt_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewText);

function viewText(e:MouseEvent):void{
var viewText:String = "viewTxtFunc";
dispatchEvent (new Event(viewText, true));
```

}

//To turn off ticker(default). Ticker mask is off/invisible by default(out of stage).

```
thisMC.tickerMaskMC.y = 160;
```

//custom event received on child swf

```
parent.stage.addEventListener("viewTxtFunc", eventHandler);
function eventHandler(e:Event):void{
tickerMaskMC.y = 194;
```

}

Comment: mmm, don't really understand everything. but do you have some code snippets you could post here?

Comment: I have added some a lot of code I guess, will you help please

Answer (score 0):

Use your parent swf as the controller for all of your child swf's.

When a child swf wants to communicate to another child, send an event or call up to the parent swf and then back down to the other child swf that you want to receive the call.

Though in your example it sounds more like you're having a layering issue than a communication issue. If you want to assure that when you click next or back that if the ticker is active, it stays active, then be sure to load that new swf in a DisplayObject that is behind the ticker DisplayObject. In this instance both DisplayObjects are your loaded swf's.

Take a look at the getChildAt and addChildAt methods of DisplayObject. The first DisplayObject added to the Stage or another DisplayObject will have an index of 0, the second will be 1 and so and so forth. Using that you should be able to correctly layer your ticker to always stay on top and be displayed when you want it to be

**Update from your comments:** 
You could look into an Object called LoaderContext. It has a property called parameters on it which is an object you just pass along with the load request for your SWF.

`var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext; 

var thisLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 

lc.parameters = { "tickerHeight" : "myVariable" }; 

thisLoader.load(new URLRequest(clips[swf_no]), lc);`

Then in the child swf try: 
`trace(loaderInfo.parameters.tickerHeight);`

I forgot to add this as well, your compiled SWF target must be at least version 10.2 or higher to use LoaderContext

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please correct me if I am wrong. I don't think it is a layering issue because when I load child swf 2, the child swf 1 gets unloaded (using unloadAndStop) and removed from stage. I know what I want to do but I am not able to write the code. I will explain: When first child swf is loaded, the default value of ticker_mc.y should be 160. I want to hold this value in a variable. When I click ticker active btn, position of ticker_mc changes to 194 so the value of variable should change to 194. When I click next btn, the variable value(160 or 194)should be sent to next child and

Comment: and position of ticker_mc should be equal to variable value (160 or 194). I will add some of the code that will help you understand my problem better.Thanks

Comment: code in parent swf:var whatEver:Number = 194; thisLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initialized); function initialized(e:Event) { MovieClip(thisLoader.content).myVariable = whatEver;//set the value of the child variable to its own. MovieClip(thisLoader.content).updateTextField();//call a function in the child just to display it } code in child swf: var myVariable:Number = 150; function updateTextField():void { trace(myVariable + " child 1"); if(myVariable == 194){ tickerMaskMC.y = 194; } } updateTextField();

Comment: I am  able to make ticker on loading with above code and it also stays active when I click next btn. Now, I want this to happen only when I click view btn,not when the child swf loads. Can someone help please?

Comment: var tickerPos:uint = thisMC.tickerMaskMC.y; addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); function onEnterFrame (event:Event):void { tickerPos = thisMC.tickerMaskMC.y; trace(thisMC.tickerMaskMC.y); If I write this code in doneLoading function, I can trace the values 160 and 194 based on whether I have clicked ticker inactive or active btn. Is there any way I can pass these values (160 or 194)  to next loaded swf and position tickerMaskMC accordingly without getting 1009 and 1010 errors.